# Distributed Coordination - SpringBoot Application hard dependency on implementing frameworks such as etcd, zookeeper etc

Tags: apache-zookeeper, consul, etcd

My current application is using zookeeper which is a hard dependency for the boot-up status. Whenever zookeeper server connection is disconnected or timed-out, application would also go offine and keep retrying for the connection.

Does the following frameworks provide such hard dependency to make application go offline.
etcd, consul, Hazelcast etc..